# MySQL - How to use fields in 'LIKE' operator

Tags: mysql, comparison, field, sql-like

I want to do a 'select' in MySQL using the operator 'LIKE'.

But I do not want to use text as a comparison factor. I want to compare text between two fields in same table, like this:

> SELECT field1,field2 FROM table WHERE field2 LIKE %field1% ;

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM table 
WHERE field2 LIKE CONCAT('%', field1, '%');
```

Comment: SELECT field1,field2 FROM table WHERE field2 LIKE CONCAT('%', field2, '%');

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can use:

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table WHERE field2 LIKE '%' + field1 '%' ;
```